# Git error while push, it recommand to pull, but pull also fails

Tags: git, github, netbeans

Question: When `git push` throws error.

```bash
sudhakar@featuriz-ubuntu:~/NB/2023/pro$ git push                                                                                                                      
Password for 'https://featuriz@github.com': 
To https://github.com/featuriz/pro.git
 ! [rejected]        development -> development (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/featuriz/pro.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

As per this when I `git pull`

```bash
sudhakar@featuriz-ubuntu:~/NB/2023/pro$ git pull
Password for 'https://featuriz@github.com': 
From https://github.com/featuriz/pro
 * [new branch]      Modified   -> origin/Modified
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
hint: your next pull:
hint: 
hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge (the default strategy)
hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
hint: 
hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
hint: invocation.
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

**NOTE:-** What I want is, my desktop content. It should be updated to github. `local -> remote`

**As per Git Doc:-**

```
The git pull command is used to fetch and download content 
from a remote repository and immediately update 
the local repository to match that content. 
Merging remote upstream changes into your local repository is a 
common task in Git-based collaboration work flows.
```

I'm afraid to play with git commands

Comment: No `?` appears in your post, so by definition you have not asked a question. Update your post accordingly. It is not clear (to me) what you are asking, and without an actual question it may be closed for the reason _"This question should include more details and clarify the problem."_

Comment: _"What I want is, my desktop content only. Not the remote one."_... then don't do anything. You can continue to work on your own copy without updating from the remote but you won't be able to push until you rebase or merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means there are new commits on the remote branch `origin/development` ("upstream"), but also new commits on your local branch `development`.

There are different ways to resolve this, depending on what you *really* want:

a) I want to push my new commits without deleting the new commits from the remote branch. I'm okay with the creation of a merge-commit that will consolidate the two different commit histories back into one.

```
git pull --no-ff
git push origin HEAD
```

b) I want to push my new commits without deleting the new commits from the remote branch. I do *not* want a merge-commit to be created. Instead I just want to (automatically) recreate my commits on top of the new commits from the remote, so that there is no split in history (and therefore no merge required).

```
git pull --rebase
git push origin HEAD
```

c) I want to push my new commits and **DELETE**(!!!) the new commits from the remote branch.

```
git push --force-with-lease origin HEAD
```

Note that in cases a) and b) there might be merge-conflicts that need resolving if the new commits of both sides modified the same files/code.

However, in case of c) the new commits from the remote side will be removed from the remote branch. Which is usually *not* what you want in a repository you share with other people, except when those commits were added by somebody by mistake.

Comment: I wouldn't say c) is rare and usually *not* what you want, except maybe for public repos. I'd guess that c) is possibly the most common case for personal repos, and also personal branches in shared private repos.

Comment: Thanks for c), it is what I'm searching.

Comment: @TTT Fair enough. I tend do underestimate people's love for amending/recreating commits :D